# Remove trailing numbers

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Why I get trailing so many numbers when I run below code?

```
BigDecimal lat =  new BigDecimal(0.0077);

System.out.println(lat);
```

> output >>
>   0.00770000000000000024702462297909733024425804615020751953125

I want to print exactly what I entered. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most finite decimal fractions cannot be exactly represented by floating-point, so that is the approximation you get when you create the floating-point literal `0.0077`.

To avoid the problem, use the constructor [`BigDecimal(String val)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29) instead:

```
BigDecimal lat = new BigDecimal("0.0077");
```

As @TimB points out, if you already have a `double` value, you can also use:

```
BigDecimal lat = BigDecimal.valueOf(doubleVal);
```

Also, here is the mandatory reference to [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: That first sentence is highly misleading.  You probably mean something like "Most finite decimal fractions cannot be exactly represented by floating-point."

Comment: @Oli: True, I changed it to your wording.

Comment: The string constructor works for constants but not for all cases, `BigDecimal.valueOf` is better

Comment: @TimB In which version of Java? In 7, `BigDecimal.valueOf(String)` doesn't even exist.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf%28double%29

Comment: @Tim: That is the same thing as `new BigDecimal(Double.toString(double))`, so it works for the same cases. It is a pretty nice shorthand though.

Comment: Yep, in cases where you have a constant i.e. "0.77" then `new BigDecimal()` is fine. If you have a `double` value being passed into a method though then `BigDecimal.valueOf()` is cleaner.

Comment: @Marko: A small program demonstrating the difference between `new BigDecimal(double)` and `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)`: https://ideone.com/mbyLmd

Comment: Nevermind, I read the Javadoc :) I really didn't expect such a difference in behavior.

Answer (score 3):

When you have a number like `0.077` this cannot be exactly represented and in fact you get a number which is almost this, but with a small error.  When you print this number as a string, the code to do this "knows" to discard the small error and you see the number you expect.

BigDecimal tries to give you a faithful representation and it is doing what it should even if this is surprising.  What you want to use is the following method

```
BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(0.077);
```

In this case the BigDecimal takes the value as it would be printed, instead of the true value represented.

> why is it so long?

To accurately represent a 53-bit fraction (double has a 53-bit mantissa) you need 53 decimal digits. e.g. every time you multiple by 10 to get another digit, you multiple 2 (and 5) which makes the lower bit 0 and eventually you guarentee to have all 0 bits and no more digits.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   System.out.println(String.format("%.4f",lat));
```

where `4` `in %.4f` specified how many decimal places you want to display

Note that this will only format your output display. the actual value of lat however still `0.00770000000000000024702462297909733024425804615020751953125`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [**NumberFormat**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)  and specify the fraction digits `setMinimumFractionDigits(4)`

```
BigDecimal lat =  new BigDecimal(0.0077);
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(4);
System.out.println(nf.format(lat));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 BigDecimal lat =  new BigDecimal(0.0077);
 lat=lat.setScale(4,RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
 System.out.println(lat);
```